# Fail to install ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to run the following command and get the following error, any idea how to fix it?

```
npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/getting-started/
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the version compatibility of different packages in the project. I had to install a lower version of ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding **"--build-from-source"** to the end of your install command

Comment: The installation process failed:(

Comment: take a look at this: https://harsh-patel.medium.com/node-gyp-error-gyp-failed-with-exit-code-1-macos-npm-5aeaf75996d4

Answer (score 0):

Please try using 'npm i ag-grid-community ag-grid-angular --legacy-peer-deps'

The --legacy-peer-deps tells the npm to ignore the peer dependencies and continue the installation of the package.